# node package manager command does not work anymore

Tags: npm, proxy

While trying to set the proxy setting for npm, I accidentally gave in an incorrect character in the url.

I've used this command:

```
npm config set proxy http://<username>:<pwd>@host:port

npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<pwd>@host:port
```

The invalid character was in the user-section.

Now when I run any npm command, the following error occurs:

> ```
> URIError: URI malformed
>     at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
>     at Url.parse (url.js:343:19)
>     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:154:13)
>     at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:173:13)
>     at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:222:24)
>     at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:188:11)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:105:12
>     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:71:15
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:59
>       throw new Error('npm.load() required')
>       ^
>
> Error: npm.load() required
>     at Object.get (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\npm.js:59:13)
>     at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:32)
> ←[90m    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)←[39m ←[90m    at
> process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:165:25)←[39m
> URIError: URI malformed
>     at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
>     at Url.parse (url.js:343:19)
>     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:154:13)
>     at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:173:13)
>     at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:222:24)
>     at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:188:11)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:105:12
>
> D:\src\reporting-app>npm config delete http-proxy URIError: URI
> malformed
>     at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
>     at Url.parse (url.js:343:19)
>     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:154:13)
>     at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:173:13)
>     at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:222:24)
>     at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:188:11)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:105:12
>     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:71:15
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:59
>       throw new Error('npm.load() required')
>       ^
>
> Error: npm.load() required
>     at Object.get (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\npm.js:59:13)
>     at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:32)
> ←[90m    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)←[39m ←[90m    at
> process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:165:25)←[39m
> URIError: URI malformed
>     at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
>     at Url.parse (url.js:343:19)
>     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:154:13)
>     at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:173:13)
>     at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:222:24)
>     at validate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:188:11)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:105:12
>     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
>     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nopt\lib\nopt.js:71:15
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:59
>       throw new Error('npm.load() required')
>       ^
>
> Error: npm.load() required
>     at Object.get (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\npm.js:59:13)
>     at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:32)
> ←[90m    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)←[39m ←[90m    at
> process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:165:25)←[39m
> ```

Now to fix this problem, I have to correct the proxy url somehow manually, but I can't find the proxy settings.

- I already checked the `.npmrc` file but it is empty.
- I also tried to reinstall nodejs but it did not work.

Does anyone have any clue?

Thanks

Comment: try `npm cache clear --force` or `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I cant use the npm command, the error occures in every npm command.

Comment: Try reinistalling node. worth a try

Comment: @RanjithVaratharajan I does not work either, I think the proxy setting is somewhere in the registry or in a file.

Comment: @Leon, type 'set ' in command prompt, you'll see all the environment variables. If you see something like HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY, try setting it to null.

Comment: @RanjithVaratharajan Unfortunately I dont see anything like that.

Comment: try deleting the .npmrc in your project and then try running npm command.

Comment: @RanjithVaratharajan Doesnt work either, the problem occures not only in my project it occures globally on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I could not find the correct .npmrc file, because I had a few files with the same name in diffrent locations on my machine.

So I have made a check on my whole C:\ disk and after searching several files, I have found the correct .npmrc file, that had the invalid settings.